# Evaluate $\int_{c}(yi+zj+xk).dr $ where$C$ is the given curve.

Tags: calculus

Evaluate  $\int_{c}(yi+zj+xk).dr $ where$ C $ is the intersection of $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1$ and $x+y=0$ transversed in the clockwise direction when viewed from point $(1,1,0)$.

I can use Stokes theorem to solve this problem, if I integrate the curl of $F$ on the surface $x+y=0$. 
I don't know how to take projection then. Solving both the equation of sphere and $x+y=0$, then direct line integration is making the calculations complicated.
Any hint$?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ${\bf F}(x,y,z):=(y,z,x)$ is linear in $x$, $y$, $z$ the curl of ${\bf F}$ is constant, namely $${\rm curl}({\bf F})=(-1,-1,-1)\ .$$ At the same time the unit normal ${\bf n}$ of the disc $D$ bounded by the curve $C$ is constant as well. Taking care of the orientation one has $${\bf n}={1\over\sqrt{2}}(-1,-1,0)\ .$$ Furthermore the radius of $C=\partial D$ is $1$. Therefore Stokes' theorem gives
$$\int_C{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}=\int_D{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=(-1,-1,-1)\cdot{1\over\sqrt{2}}(-1,-1,0)\>{\rm area}(D)=\sqrt{2}\,\pi\ .$$